# Creating menu item in controller and display it in view in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am creating menu in controller and just want to display that menu in view (in my case it is an element) but the problem is the part of the menu which controller is creating is not appended to the part which is already created in view. I do not have much idea about creating html codes in controller and rendering in view in Cakephp. Please help to sort out my issue. My code snippet is :

> Controller Code:

```
     public function sub_categories($id){
        $categories = $this->Categories->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('parent IN'=>$id)))->toArray();
        $i=0;
        foreach($categories as $p_cat){
            $cat_id=$p_cat['category_id'];
            $categories[$i]['sub'] = $this->sub_categories($cat_id);
            $i++;
        }
        return $categories;       
    }


    public function get_categories()
    {
        $categories = $this->Categories->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('parent IN'=>'0')))->toArray();
        $i=0;
        foreach($categories as $p_cat){


            $categories[$i]['sub'] = $this->sub_categories($p_cat['category_id']);
            $i++;
        }

        return $categories;

    }


    public function fetch_menu($data){

    foreach($data as $menu){

        echo "<li class='dropdown menu__item'>";
        echo "<a href=# class='dropdown-toggle menu__link' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>".$menu->category_name."<span class='caret'></span></a>";



        if(!empty($menu->sub)){

          echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3'>";
          echo "<div class='agile_inner_drop_nav_info'>"; 


            echo $this->fetch_sub_menu($menu->sub);



            echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</ul>";  
        }
        echo "</li>"; 

    }

}



public function fetch_sub_menu($sub_menu){



    foreach($sub_menu as $menu){
       echo "<div class='col-sm-3 multi-gd-img'>";
        echo "<ul class='multi-column-dropdown'>";
        echo "<li><a href='mens.html'>";
        echo $menu->category_name;
        echo "</a></li>";


     echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";



        if(!empty($menu->sub)){




        echo "<ul class='multi-column-dropdown'>";




echo "<li>";
echo $this->fetch_sub_menu($menu->sub);
echo "</li>";



 echo "</ul>";

    }

    }

}


   public function display()
    {

        $data = $this->get_categories();
        $menu=$this->fetch_menu($data);
         $this->set(compact('menu')); 
    }
```

> View Code:

```
<li class=" menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">About</a></li>

<?php 
echo $menu;
?>....
```

Comment: Based on the code you pasted here I strongly recommend you to read the manual first before trying to work with the framework. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html Read everything under "Getting started" and then do a tutorial. Also tag the right version. You've tagged Cake2 and Cake3 - it's impossible to use both within the same code...Use the right tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please update your fetch_menu function like this
here i am just replaced your "echo" with a variable and single quotes with double quotes and double quotes with single quotes. and return the variable

```
public function fetch_menu($data){
  $menu = "";
  foreach($data as $val){

    $menu.= '<li class="dropdown menu__item">';
    $menu.= '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu__link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'.$val->category_name.'<span class="caret"></span></a>';



    if(!empty($val->sub)){

      $menu.='<ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">';
      $menu.='<div class="agile_inner_drop_nav_info">'; 


        $menu.=$this->fetch_sub_menu($val->sub);



        $menu.='<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        $menu.='</div>';
        $menu.='</ul>';  
    }
    $menu.='</li>'; 
   }
  return $menu;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. How will i display $menu->category_name in between <li> tag. I got this error Trying to get property of non-object where i am trying to save my category_name in menu variable.

Comment: i am sorry, i dont clearly understand your question. please let me know it

Comment: who downvoted my answer as not usefull? it was usefull for the needer.